# What depends when a character ends up been considered in a specific "composition"?

Tags: php, regex, unicode, utf-8, pcre

In Unicode, a character can be considered in different "compositions".

For example the character `à` which codepoint is `U+00E0`, it's also composed of two code points: `U+0061` combined with the grave accent `U+0300`.

Which left the question of:

What depends when a character ends up been considered in a specific composition?
I mean: The Keyboard? Encoding? Copy-Pasted Text?

I know the way to be aware of with the `\X` metacharacter, but I would like that someone explain my wondering.

Comment: Always run your input through NFD when it gets to you and through NFC when it leaves you, and use `\X` whenever you want a grapheme, and you will be much less unhappy. See perhaps [my OSCON talks](http://training.perl.com/OSCON2011/index.html) about these matters.

Comment: @tchrist OMG great reference, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ultimately up to the operating system which code point(s) they store when you hit a key, although there is convention in the form of the normalized forms (specifically NFC):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization

Copy-and-paste copies code points, not concepts-of-graphemes (Grapheme is a less ambiguous term, since character can mean both grapheme and code point).

If you're converting from some other character set to Unicode, then the conversion mapping will dictate what code points you end up with and it nearly always matches how the source character set encodes composite characters - where the source character set has a single code point for a LATIN A WITH UMLAUT, then Unicode will too.

Comment: No, Unicode has no “umlauts”; it has diaereses. You are perhaps thinking of U+00C4 `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS` and others like that.

Comment: hah, true, i had just made that one up. though the standard does say that for U+0308 (`COMBINING DIAERESIS`) it's also known as `double dot above, umlaut`. but anyway, when the *source* character set has what it calls a-with-umlaut, then Unicode will have a single composed form of that character, even if it calls it something different.

Comment: Thank you very much Cal for your explanation and reference, thank you.